# How to attach pdf in mail of html content in mail on form submit using php?

Tags: php, email, pdf

I want to attach a pdf file of html content when form submit.

Html form is made with css so pdf is generated with css.

generated pdf has attached in mail on form submit.

Comment: *so pdf is generated with css* what does it mean?

Comment: i don't want plain text

Comment: You want it to be styled, ok. Try to clarify in your question, I'm sorry, but it seems too vague...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to send email. I hope you have created file to attach so you can pass file name i fuction.

```
    function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {

    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";

    // Messages for testing only, nobody will see them unless this script URL is visited manually
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "Message sent!";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR sending message.";
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using Phpmailer function

Comment: use this line to add attachment:                                                                                          $mail->addAttachment(filename); //to add attachment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phpmailer fuction so this code will help you to send pdf file:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.server.net";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "username@domain.com";
    $mail->Password = "password1";
    $mail->From = "username@domain.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Software something";
    $mail->AddAddress("targetguy@domain.com", "Target Guy");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("username@domain.com", "Software Simian");
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Subject";
    $mail->Body    = "Message";
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags("Message:);
    $mail->AddAttachment("filename.pdf"); 
    if(!$mail->Send()){
      $resultstatus = 'Failed';
    }
```

Comment: I know how to send attach file with phpmailer, but my question is that convert my current html page in pdf and send mail with attach pdf when form submit.